# Difference between colorPrimary with android: or without in themes.xml

Tags: android, android-theme

Can I know what is the difference between `colorPrimary` with `android:` or without.

```
<item name="colorPrimary">...</item>
<item name="android:colorPrimary">...</item>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one with the `android:` prefix is defined in the Android SDK, the other one is defined in your app. You can change the value of your color, but you should't be able to change the system one (I don't even know where it is used).

Comment: Sorry, but this isn't really correct. Both of those are theme attributes that you can provide values for in your app's themes. The `ActionBar` color, for example, is set from this value. The difference is that the one without the prefix is (most likely) from the support/androidx library, which defines its own 'colorPrimary` attribute so it can be used on Android versions before it was introduced in the platform in API level 21, allowing for consistent theming across versions. Platform `View`s will use the one with the `android` prefix. Library `View`s will use the one without.